# How fix compilation error on spray example?

Tags: scala, types, spray

Spray documentation has example about [onComplete](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-routing/future-directives/onComplete/) directive

I copied example:

```
path("divide" / IntNumber / IntNumber) { (a, b) =>
        onComplete(divide(a, b)) {
          case Success(value: Any) => complete(s"The result was $value")
          case Failure(ex)    => complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}")
        }
      }
def divide(a: Int, b: Int): Future[Int] = Future {
  a / b
}
```

And I got error:

```
Type mismatch, expected: onCompleteFutureMagnet[NoninferedT], actual Future[Int]
```

It is seems that something very simple missed in code.

Spray version is 1.3.1

**Updated**

I have downloaded spray sources and see same compilation errors in FutureDirectivesSpec.

Comment: You need to make sure an implicit `ExecutionContext` is in scope. If you are seeing the same problem compiling spray itself, can you post the exact steps you took for compiling spray?

Comment: Can you show us your imports? Perhaps you are missing some implicit.

Answer (score 7):

```
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

works for me